# How to close a popup window in sahi?

Tags: sahi

' How to close a popup window in sahi ?

```
 if(_windowExists("Technischer Fehler"))
 {
 _click(_link("SCHLIESSEN"));
 }
else
```

{

}
I get the error WindowExists is not defined whereas I have already defined it at the start of the program as var windowExists = "Technischer Fehler";

Can anyone please guide'

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/popup-windows.html#_windowExists

```
var $exists = _windowExists("/demo/");
```

haven't used Sahi in a while, but if i remember correctly, you can't just use the Sahi API in if statements. Yeah https://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/fetch-apis.html#Generic%20attribute%20fetching%20mechanism you have to use `_condition`.

```
if (_condition(_windowExists("Technischer Fehler"))) { ...
```